# How to get dynamic Image url path in ng App

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to give an image a dynamic and relative path.

**scenario**: 2 separate projects, first: webapi net core, and the second: angular app.
in the ng app I have a component employeelist, when u click on a row, the details panel of the employee appears, of which the photo is a part of.
Is there a way to get the path of the photo dynamic? the photos are in a folder within the first project (webapi project) -see picture

```
<div mat-card-avatar *ngIf="!(sourceImageFile == undefined)" style="background: url('/Documents/companies/employees/Images/'{{sourceImageFile}})" class="header-image">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]
I converted the photo stream to base64 in the api.

```
var employeeImagePath = BaseDocumentsPath + folderName + "\\employees\\Images\\" + fileName; 
byte[] fileStream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(employeeImagePath);
var imageextension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Substring(1);
var imagedata = Convert.ToBase64String(fileStream);
var empPicViewModel = new EmployeePictureViewModel
{
Image = imagedata
};
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empPicViewModel);
return result;
```

After that, in the ng App, in the call to the web api, I create objectUrl in the following way:

```
this.service.getConvertedEmployeeImage(fileName).subscribe((data: any) =>{

    let objectUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64, ' + data["Image"];
    this.sourceImageFile = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectUrl);
  });
```

The html looks like this:

```
<img [src]="sourceImageFile" alt="">
```